# Screenshot before windows starts: without another computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, screenshot

I'm pretty sure that this must have been asked before, but haven't found a duplicate question, thus I shall ask again...

Is it possible to take a screenshot of my computer before the OS boots up WITHOUT an external computer or virtualization software like VMWare?? e.g. at the BIOS, or the "Windows is Loading" screen, even at the login screen?

Is it possible to take screenshots of BSODs as well?

EDIT: I'm using a desktop pc running Windows 7 Ultimate in a home environment.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On desktop computers, no. On server computers you can use the remote management utilities, if they support it. See:

1. http://www-03.ibm.com/products/retail/products/software/rsm/rma/index.html
2. http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/remotemgmt.html

Comment: Well, thanks for answering. Guess I forgot to mention I'm using a home desktop computer :)

Comment: You can always take one with a camera!

Comment: I was hoping for something of higher quality :P without the gloss of a screen.

Comment: It would have to be a utility that you build into the bios...Unless you have a company that wants that to happen or an open source bios i can't see it ever happening.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to pay for it you could use something like http://www.vgacapture.com/

Comment: Well, it's probably not worth the money. I'll just take the answer as "no". :)

Comment: or something put between the connections. That works too. software wise tho you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day if you pressed the PrtScn button while a printer was hooked up to the parallel port the PC would send the screen to the printer. This would even work in the BIOS screens.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/184193-48-print-bios-windows

I personally would just use a digital camera and put up with the non-perfect image.